# Real time sync between mongodb and elastic search

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Using Logstash-input-mongodb able to insert records at real time. But when it comes to update, that is not happening as expected. Can anyone guide me on this.

**logstash-mongodb.conf**

```
input {
    mongodb {
        uri => 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test-db'
        placeholder_db_dir => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/'
        placeholder_db_name => 'logstash_sqlite.db'
        collection => 'mycol'
        batch_size => 5000
        generateId => true
    }
}
filter{
    mutate { remove_field => "_id" }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "http://localhost:9200" ]
        index => "test-index"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your query_delay ?

Comment: when i am insert data in mongodb auto sync happening in ES through logstash-input-mongodb pulgin. but what is query_delay in your context?

Comment: " query_delay
    (time units) The number of seconds behind real time that data is queried. For example, if data from 10:04 a.m. might not be searchable in Elasticsearch until 10:06 a.m., set this property to 120 seconds. The default value is 60s. "

Comment: @LeBigCat insertion of the record working fine between mongodb and elk. But when its comes to updation its not working as expected. and logstash always comparing with last record of mongodb. query is as follows.  _MONGODB | QUERY | namespace=test-db.mycol selector={:_id=>{:$gt=>BSON::ObjectId('5c125641a9fbde5aa43f8658')}}_ . let me know if you need conf file of logstash

Comment: Yeah join your logstash config. I thinck you have an issue on the update part.

Comment: @LeBigCat I have attached the logstash confing file. Please have a look

Comment: I dont see action => "update" in your logstash config.

Comment: @shaan26 : Did the above mentioned configuration worked for you?